# Automatically generate sequences and triggers for all tables in Oracle

Tags: oracle, triggers, sequence, dynamic-sql

In my schema, I've migrated about 250 tables from SQL Server to Oracle. The thing is, no sequences or triggers have been created for any of these tables.

Is there an easy way to generate all the table sequences and triggers rather than manually doing this for every table?

An example of a sequence I need would be:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE "SYSTEM"."SEC_USERS_ID_SEQ"  
    MINVALUE 0 MAXVALUE 999999999999999999999999 
    INCREMENT BY 1 
    START WITH 23 
    CACHE 20 
    NOORDER NOCYCLE NOPARTITION;
```

And the trigger:

```
create or replace TRIGGER SEC_USERS_TRIG 
before INSERT 
ON "SYSTEM"."SEC_USERS" 
FOR EACH row 
BEGIN 
    IF inserting THEN 
       IF :NEW."ID" IS NULL THEN
          SELECT SEC_USERS_ID_SEQ.nextval INTO :NEW."ID" FROM dual;
       END IF;
    END IF;
END;
```

Comment: What does generating triggers mean? What do they do?

Comment: Triggers to run sequences which increment ID's on insert/update

Comment: You may have a look at tables with auto increment PK, with no need for triggers.

Comment: If you are using Oracle 12c then you can use [identity columns](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/statements_7002.htm#CJAECCFH) and do not need a sequence or a trigger.

Comment: @MT0 how do I generate these for all my tables? (I would like to set the keys on the ID column that is for each table)

Comment: Do all of your tables have an id column named id? I think this should be possible with dynamically generating queries to run in PL/SQL based on table names.

Comment: @Azarix You cannot modify a column to be an identity column - you need to specify it when you create the table/column so you would need to modify the scripts you are using to create/migrate the database.

Comment: Incidentally it is bad practice to use the SYSTEM schema for application objects. You need to create a user for your use.

Answer (score 2):

We can generate scripts using the Oracle data dictionary views (the equivalent of MSSQL INFORMATION_SCHEMA). [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-8865F65B-EF6D-44A5-B0A1-3179EFF0C36A.htm).

This example generates CREATE SEQUENCE statements. I have followed your example and accepted the default values, which don't need to be coded. The sequence name is derived from table name concatenated with column name and suffixed with "_SEQ". Watch out for [Oracle's thirty character limit on object names](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF51129)!

This loop dynamically queries the table to get the current maximum value of the Primary Key column, which is used to derive the STARTS WITH clause.

```
declare
    curr_mx number;
begin
    for lrec in ( select ucc.table_name
                         , ucc.column_name
                  from user_constraints uc
                       join user_cons_columns ucc
                           on ucc.table_name = uc.table_name
                          and ucc.constraint_name = uc.constraint_name
                       join user_tab_columns utc
                          on utc.table_name = ucc.table_name
                          and utc.column_name = ucc.column_name
                  where uc.constraint_type = 'P' -- primary key
                  and   utc.data_type = 'NUMBER' -- only numeric columns
                  )
    loop
        execute immediate 'select max ('|| lrec.column_name ||') from ' ||lrec.table_name 
            into curr_mx;
        if curr_mx is null then
            curr_mx := 0;
        end if;
        dbms_output.put_line('CREATE SEQUENCE "'|| user || '"."'
            || lrec.table_name ||'_'|| lrec.column_name || '_SEQ" '
            ||' START WITH ' || to_char( curr_mx + 1 )  ||';'
        );
    end loop;
end;
/
```

This code uses [DBMS_OUTPUT](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_output.htm#BABJCAJA), so you can spool it to a file for later use. If you're using an IDE like SQL Developer you may need to enable DBMS_OUTPUT. Follow the guidance in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7889380/146325).

If you can guarantee that all your tables have a primary key which is a numeric column called ID then you can simplify the select statement. Contrariwise, if some of your primary keys are compound constraints you will need to handle that.

Obviously I plumped for generating sequences because they're simpler. Writing the more complex trigger implementation is left as an exercise for the reader :)

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not very experienced with Oracle. I ran the script but I don't exactly know what it's doing

Comment: @Azarix it should print a sequence creation statement for every table (that has a numeric primary key) you have. You can than run those and create the sequences. Analogical procedure can be done to generate trigger creation scripts.

Comment: @Deltharis where are these sequences stored? I ran the code you wrote but when i check the sequences folder, it's still empty

Comment: DBMS_OUTPUT writes to a screen. If you use an IDE like TOAD then that should handle it. If you're using SQL*Plus then `set serveroutput on size unlimited` before running the code. Use `spool` command to save to a file, Please understand that Oracle databases know nothing about your directory structure and don't understand "sequences folder".

Comment: @APC I'm currently using SQL Developer

Comment: You probably haven't enabled DBMS_OUTPUT. Follow the guidance in [this StackOverflow answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7889380/146325)

Answer (score 2):

thanks for the script. I altered it a little bit and did the trigger implementation. Feel free to use it.

```
declare
    curr_mx number;
    counter number;
    seq_name varchar2 (30);
    trigger_name varchar2 (30);
begin
    for lrec in ( select ucc.table_name
                         , ucc.column_name
                  from user_constraints uc
                       join user_cons_columns ucc
                           on ucc.table_name = uc.table_name
                          and ucc.constraint_name = uc.constraint_name
                       join user_tab_columns utc
                          on utc.table_name = ucc.table_name
                          and utc.column_name = ucc.column_name
                  where uc.constraint_type = 'P' -- primary key
                  and   utc.data_type = 'NUMBER' -- only numeric columns
                  )
    loop
        execute immediate 'select (max ('|| lrec.column_name ||')+1) from ' ||lrec.table_name 
            into curr_mx;

        IF curr_mx is null THEN
            curr_mx := 0;
        END IF;

        IF counter is null THEN
            counter := 0;
        END IF;    

        /* check length of sequence name, 30 is max */
        IF length(lrec.table_name ||'_'|| lrec.column_name || '_SEQ') > 30 THEN

            IF length(lrec.column_name || '_SEQ') > 30 THEN

                seq_name := counter || '_PKA_SEQ';

            ELSE

                seq_name := lrec.column_name || '_SEQ';

            END IF;  

        ELSE

            seq_name := lrec.table_name ||'_'|| lrec.column_name || '_SEQ';

        END IF;

        /* check length of trigger name, 30 is max */
        IF length(lrec.table_name || '_PKA_T') > 30 THEN

            trigger_name := counter || '_PKA_T'; 

        ELSE

            trigger_name := lrec.table_name || '_PKA_T';

        END IF;        

        counter := counter +1;

        dbms_output.put_line(
          'CREATE SEQUENCE "' || seq_name || '"'
          ||' START WITH ' || to_char( curr_mx + 1 )  ||';'
        );
        dbms_output.put_line('/');
        dbms_output.put_line(
          'CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "' || trigger_name || '"' 
          || ' BEFORE INSERT ON "' || lrec.table_name || '"' 
          || ' FOR EACH ROW '
          || ' BEGIN '
          || ' :new."' || lrec.column_name || '" := "' || seq_name || '".nextval;'
          || ' END;'
        );
        dbms_output.put_line('/');

    end loop;
end;
```

I also checked if the names of the sequences and triggers are longer than 30 characters because oracle won´t accept these.

EDIT:
Had to put '/' after each line so you can execute all statements at one run.