# how to print DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE() at oracle database 10g?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using sql developer and I have oracle database 10g and DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE() doesn't print. I have tried every way.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('hello');
END;
```

With this code it only states PL/SQL procedure successfully completed. But it doesn't print hello.

Comment: That's for SQL*Plus. Does this answer your question? [Printing the value of a variable in SQL Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887413/printing-the-value-of-a-variable-in-sql-developer)

Comment: I think because your database is so old, the jdbc driver won't get your output from the buffer

Answer (score 0):

Did you turn the output on in the sql developer settings?

Try the following:

1. View -> Dbms Output
2. On a new dbms output tab there is a green cross "Enable DBMS OUTPUT for the connection". Click it

Comment: Yes,I've already tried it and it didn't make any changes. @ekochergin.

Comment: Same problem, same result: no change. Any other idea?

Comment: Hi @MichalJFigurski unfortunalely there is nothing more I can say without you sharing your screen. Perhaps you might try to run code in SQLPLUS to check whether it prints something out at all

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate the DBMS Output screen and then choose the workspace you are working too, click on the PLUS button.